# Message driven bean not receiving any messages

Tags: jakarta-ee, jms, wildfly-10, message-driven-bean, activemq-artemis

My message driven bean is not receiving any messages, though I can see that messages has been sent to the queue.

The EE container is **WildFly 10.1.0.Final** and I'm using the ***embedded* Apache ActiveMQ Artemis**. Sending messages to the queue is working fine, I have verified this using JConsole.

The message driven bean:

```
import javax.ejb.ActivationConfigProperty;
import javax.ejb.MessageDriven;
import javax.jms.JMSException;
import javax.jms.Message;
import javax.jms.MessageListener;
import javax.jms.TextMessage;

@MessageDriven(activationConfig = {
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destinationType", propertyValue = "javax.jms.Queue"),
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destination", propertyValue = "Q1"),
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "acknowledgeMode", propertyValue = "Auto-acknowledge")})
public class Q1MDB implements MessageListener {
    public void onMessage(Message message) {
        TextMessage textMessage = (TextMessage) message;

        try {
            System.out.println(textMessage.getText());
        } catch (JMSException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The code to send messages:

```
ActiveMQConnectionFactory activeMQConnectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory("vm://localhost?broker.persistent=false");
try {
    Connection connection = activeMQConnectionFactory.createConnection();
    connection.start();

    Session session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);

    Destination destination = session.createQueue("Q1");

    MessageProducer producer = session.createProducer(destination);
    producer.setDeliveryMode(DeliveryMode.NON_PERSISTENT);

    TextMessage message = session.createTextMessage("message ");

    producer.send(message);

    session.close();

} catch (JMSException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

standalone-full.xml:

```
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:ejb3:4.0">
        ...
        <mdb>
            <resource-adapter-ref resource-adapter-name="${ejb.resource-adapter-name:activemq-ra.rar}"/>
            <bean-instance-pool-ref pool-name="mdb-strict-max-pool"/>
        </mdb>
        ...
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:messaging-activemq:1.0">
        <server name="default">
            <security-setting name="#">
                <role name="guest" send="true" consume="true" create-non-durable-queue="true" delete-non-durable-queue="true"/>
            </security-setting>
            <address-setting name="#" dead-letter-address="jms.queue.DLQ" expiry-address="jms.queue.ExpiryQueue" max-size-bytes="10485760" page-size-bytes="2097152" message-counter-history-day-limit="10"/>
            <http-connector name="http-connector" socket-binding="http" endpoint="http-acceptor"/>
            <http-connector name="http-connector-throughput" socket-binding="http" endpoint="http-acceptor-throughput">
                <param name="batch-delay" value="50"/>
            </http-connector>
            <in-vm-connector name="in-vm" server-id="0"/>
            <http-acceptor name="http-acceptor" http-listener="default"/>
            <http-acceptor name="http-acceptor-throughput" http-listener="default">
                <param name="batch-delay" value="50"/>
                <param name="direct-deliver" value="false"/>
            </http-acceptor>
            <in-vm-acceptor name="in-vm" server-id="0"/>
            <jms-queue name="ExpiryQueue" entries="java:/jms/queue/ExpiryQueue"/>
            <jms-queue name="DLQ" entries="java:/jms/queue/DLQ"/>
            <jms-queue name="Q1" entries="java:/jms/queue/q1"/>
            <connection-factory name="InVmConnectionFactory" entries="java:/ConnectionFactory" connectors="in-vm"/>
            <connection-factory name="RemoteConnectionFactory" entries="java:jboss/exported/jms/RemoteConnectionFactory" connectors="http-connector"/>
            <pooled-connection-factory name="activemq-ra" entries="java:/JmsXA java:jboss/DefaultJMSConnectionFactory" connectors="in-vm" transaction="xa"/>
        </server>
    </subsystem>
```

The logs are fine:

```
09:01:29,880 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 59) WFLYSEC0002: Activating Security Subsystem
09:01:30,047 WARN  [org.jboss.as.txn] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 60) WFLYTX0013: Node identifier property is set to the default value. Please make sure it isunique.
09:01:30,080 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 52) WFLYNAM0001: Activating Naming Subsystem
09:01:30,047 INFO  [org.jboss.as.webservices] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 62) WFLYWS0002: Activating WebServices Extension
09:01:30,029 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 41) WFLYCLINF0001: Activating Infinispan subsystem.
09:01:30,097 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jsf] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 48) WFLYJSF0007: Activated the following JSF Implementations: [main]
09:01:30,419 INFO  [org.wildfly.iiop.openjdk] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 42) WFLYIIOP0001: Activating IIOP Subsystem
09:01:30,451 INFO  [org.jboss.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBoss Remoting version 4.0.21.Final
09:01:30,555 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYUT0003: Undertow 1.4.0.Final starting
09:01:30,593 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.io] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 40) WFLYIO001: Worker 'default' has auto-configured to 4 core threads with 32 task treads based on your 2 available processors
09:01:30,942 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYJCA0009: Starting JCA Subsystem (WildFly/IronJacamar 1.3.4.Final)
09:01:31,240 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 36) WFLYJCA0005: Deploying non-JDBC-compliant driver class com.ysql.jdbc.Driver (version 5.1)
09:01:31,276 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYJCA0018: Started Driver service with driver-name = mysql
09:01:31,279 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 36) WFLYJCA0004: Deploying JDBC-compliant driver class org.h2.Diver (version 1.3)
09:01:31,647 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYSEC0001: Current PicketBox version=4.9.6.Final
09:01:31,695 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 61) WFLYUT0014: Creating file handler for path 'C:\Program Files\wildfly-10.1..Final/welcome-content' with options [directory-listing: 'false', follow-symlink: 'false', case-sensitive: 'true', safe-symlink-paths: '[]']
09:01:32,448 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYNAM0003: Starting Naming Service
09:01:32,755 INFO  [org.wildfly.iiop.openjdk] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYIIOP0009: CORBA ORB Service started
09:01:32,791 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYJCA0018: Started Driver service with driver-name = h2
09:01:32,836 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYEJB0481: Strict pool slsb-strict-max-pool is using a max instance size of 32 (per class), whch is derived from thread worker pool sizing.
09:01:32,838 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYEJB0482: Strict pool mdb-strict-max-pool is using a max instance size of 8 (per class), whic is derived from the number of CPUs on this host.
09:01:32,958 INFO  [org.jboss.as.mail.extension] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYMAIL0001: Bound mail session [java:jboss/mail/Default]
09:01:33,049 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYUT0012: Started server default-server.
09:01:33,096 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYUT0018: Host default-host starting
09:01:33,357 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYJCA0001: Bound data source [java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS]
09:01:33,711 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYUT0006: Undertow HTTP listener default listening on 127.0.0.1:8080
09:01:33,898 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYSRV0027: Starting deployment of "javaee.war" (runtime-name: "javaee.war")
09:01:33,985 WARN  [org.jboss.as.domain.management.security] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYDM0111: Keystore C:\Program Files\wildfly-10.1.0.Final\standalone\confguration\application.keystore not found, it will be auto generated on first use with a self signed certificate for host localhost
09:01:33,997 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYJCA0001: Bound data source [java:jboss/datasources/javaee]
09:01:34,022 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYDS0013: Started FileSystemDeploymentService for directory C:\Program Fies\wildfly-10.1.0.Final\standalone\deployments
09:01:34,423 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.messaging-activemq] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYMSGAMQ0001: AIO wasn't located on this platform, it will fall back tousing pure Java NIO.
09:01:35,161 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 64) AMQ221000: live Message Broker is starting with configuration Broer Configuration (clustered=false,journalDirectory=C:\Program Files\wildfly-10.1.0.Final\standalone\data\activemq\journal,bindingsDirectory=C:\Program Files\wilfly-10.1.0.Final\standalone\data\activemq\bindings,largeMessagesDirectory=C:\Program Files\wildfly-10.1.0.Final\standalone\data\activemq\largemessages,pagingDirctory=C:\Program Files\wildfly-10.1.0.Final\standalone\data\activemq\paging)
09:01:35,406 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 64) AMQ221013: Using NIO Journal
09:01:35,443 INFO  [org.infinispan.factories.GlobalComponentRegistry] (MSC service thread 1-2) ISPN000128: Infinispan version: Infinispan 'Chakra' 8.2.4.Final
09:01:35,691 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYUT0006: Undertow HTTPS listener https listening on 127.0.0.1:8443
09:01:35,808 INFO  [org.infinispan.configuration.cache.EvictionConfigurationBuilder] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 69) ISPN000152: Passivation configured withou an eviction policy being selected. Only manually evicted entities will be passivated.
09:01:35,808 INFO  [org.infinispan.configuration.cache.EvictionConfigurationBuilder] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 69) ISPN000152: Passivation configured withou an eviction policy being selected. Only manually evicted entities will be passivated.
09:01:35,807 INFO  [org.infinispan.configuration.cache.EvictionConfigurationBuilder] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 66) ISPN000152: Passivation configured withou an eviction policy being selected. Only manually evicted entities will be passivated.
09:01:35,812 INFO  [org.infinispan.configuration.cache.EvictionConfigurationBuilder] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 68) ISPN000152: Passivation configured withou an eviction policy being selected. Only manually evicted entities will be passivated.
09:01:35,813 INFO  [org.infinispan.configuration.cache.EvictionConfigurationBuilder] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 68) ISPN000152: Passivation configured withou an eviction policy being selected. Only manually evicted entities will be passivated.
09:01:35,832 INFO  [org.infinispan.configuration.cache.EvictionConfigurationBuilder] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 66) ISPN000152: Passivation configured withou an eviction policy being selected. Only manually evicted entities will be passivated.
09:01:36,138 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 64) AMQ221043: Protocol module found: [artemis-server]. Adding protocl support for: CORE
09:01:36,145 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 64) AMQ221043: Protocol module found: [artemis-amqp-protocol]. Addingprotocol support for: AMQP
09:01:36,163 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 64) AMQ221043: Protocol module found: [artemis-hornetq-protocol]. Addng protocol support for: HORNETQ
09:01:36,167 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 64) AMQ221043: Protocol module found: [artemis-stomp-protocol]. Addin protocol support for: STOMP
09:01:36,226 INFO  [org.jboss.ws.common.management] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBWS022052: Starting JBossWS 5.1.5.Final (Apache CXF 3.1.6)
09:01:39,075 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYJPA0002: Read persistence.xml for javaee
09:01:39,485 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYWELD0003: Processing weld deployment javaee.war
09:01:39,596 INFO  [org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.Version] (MSC service thread 1-3) HV000001: Hibernate Validator 5.2.4.Final
09:01:39,601 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 66) WFLYJPA0010: Starting Persistence Unit (phase 1 of 2) Service 'javaee.war#javaee'
09:01:39,690 INFO  [org.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 66) HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: javaee
    ...]
09:01:40,371 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.messaging-activemq] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYMSGAMQ0016: Registered HTTP upgrade for activemq-remoting protocol hadled by http-acceptor acceptor
09:01:40,371 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.messaging-activemq] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYMSGAMQ0016: Registered HTTP upgrade for activemq-remoting protocol hadled by http-acceptor-throughput acceptor
09:01:40,371 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.messaging-activemq] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYMSGAMQ0016: Registered HTTP upgrade for activemq-remoting protocol hadled by http-acceptor acceptor
09:01:40,635 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.Version] (MSC service thread 1-3) WELD-000900: 2.3.5 (Final)
09:01:40,698 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.messaging-activemq] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYMSGAMQ0016: Registered HTTP upgrade for activemq-remoting protocol hadled by http-acceptor-throughput acceptor
09:01:40,757 INFO  [org.hibernate.Version] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 66) HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.0.10.Final}
09:01:40,819 INFO  [org.hibernate.cfg.Environment] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 66) HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
09:01:40,827 INFO  [org.hibernate.cfg.Environment] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 66) HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
09:01:41,245 INFO  [org.hibernate.annotations.common.Version] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 66) HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
09:01:41,361 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 64) AMQ221007: Server is now live
09:01:41,361 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 64) AMQ221001: Apache ActiveMQ Artemis Message Broker version 1.1.0.wldfly-017 [nodeID=f533a10c-caf1-11e7-9497-41b29e726a53]
09:01:41,545 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.messaging-activemq] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 69) WFLYMSGAMQ0002: Bound messaging object to jndi name java:jboss/eported/jms/RemoteConnectionFactory
09:01:41,614 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 67) AMQ221003: trying to deploy queue jms.queue.DLQ
09:01:41,648 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 64) AMQ221003: trying to deploy queue jms.queue.ExpiryQueue
09:01:41,648 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 66) WFLYJPA0010: Starting Persistence Unit (phase 2 of 2) Service 'javaee.war#javaee'
09:01:41,653 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 70) AMQ221003: trying to deploy queue jms.queue.Q1
09:01:41,655 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.messaging-activemq] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 68) WFLYMSGAMQ0002: Bound messaging object to jndi name java:/ConnecionFactory
09:01:41,708 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYJCA0007: Registered connection factory java:/JmsXA
09:01:41,909 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.ra] (MSC service thread 1-2) Resource adaptor started
09:01:41,910 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.services.resourceadapters.ResourceAdapterActivatorService$ResourceAdapterActivator] (MSC service thread 1-2) IJ020002 Deployed: file://RaActivatoractivemq-ra
09:01:41,943 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYJCA0002: Bound JCA ConnectionFactory [java:/JmsXA]
09:01:41,944 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.messaging-activemq] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYMSGAMQ0002: Bound messaging object to jndi name java:jboss/DefaultJMSonnectionFactory
09:01:41,984 INFO  [org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 66) HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
09:01:42,149 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYEJB0042: Started message driven bean 'Q1MDB' with 'activemq-ra.rar' resource adapter
09:01:42,186 INFO  [org.hibernate.envers.boot.internal.EnversServiceImpl] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 66) Envers integration enabled? : true
09:01:43,143 INFO  [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 66) HHH000227: Running hbm2ddl schema export
09:01:43,297 INFO  [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 66) HHH000230: Schema export complete
09:01:45,064 INFO  [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72) Initializing Mojarra 2.2.13.SP1 20160303-1204 for contet '/javaee'
09:01:48,030 INFO  [org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy_jaxrs.i18n] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72) RESTEASY002225: Deploying javax.ws.rs.core.Application: class org.boss.weld.proxies.ResourceConfig$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy
09:01:48,113 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72) WFLYUT0021: Registered web context: /javaee
09:01:48,227 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 37) WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "javaee.war" (runtime-name : "javaee.war")
09:01:48,479 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0060: Http management interface listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990/management
09:01:48,479 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0051: Admin console listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990
09:01:48,480 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0025: WildFly Full 10.1.0.Final (WildFly Core 2.2.0.Final) started in 24788ms - Started 490 of737 services (422 services are lazy, passive or on-demand)
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: How specifically are you using JConsole to confirm the message was sent properly?  Are you also using JConsole to confirm there is a consumer on the queue?

Comment: I can see that the queue attribute `QueueSize` is increased everytime i run the code to send messages. However, the `ConsumerCount` is still zero.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this problem is the way you're referencing the "destination" in the activation configuration of the MDB.  You've specified "Q1" which is not a JNDI name, and since it is not a JNDI name the Artemis JCA RA will assume you're trying to use the implementation name of the underlying core queue (which if it can't find it will simply create).  However, you've define a JMS queue whose name is "Q1" which I believe will result in a core queue named "jms.queue.Q1".  Therefore, you should either specify "jms.queue.Q1" (i.e. the actual name of the underlying core queue) or use "java:/jms/queue/q1" (i.e. the JNDI name of the queue).

Comment: Thanks Justin, I really appreciate your help. Unfortunately it didn't work, I tried both "jms.queue.Q1" and "java:/jms/queue/q1". None worked. But, I found this in the log during deployment: 


`11:28:37,307 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.ra] (default-threads - 1) AMQ151001: Attempting to reconnect org.apache.activemq.artemis.ra.inflow.ActiveMQActivationSpec(ra=org.apache.activemq.artemis.ra.ActiveMQResourceAdapter@78712571 destination=jms.queue.Q1 destinationType=javax.jms.Queue ack=Auto-acknowledge durable=false clientID=null user=null maxSession=15)`